# Custom button on CRM Mail merge window

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to put custom button on CRM Mail merge window and on click of that button , i want to store that document in sharepoint site document library.

please check below screen

[image]

Is it possible to put custom button?

Comment: This is unsupported: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531193.aspx and improbable with CRM Online.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in supported way.

Answer (score 0):

like Andrii said this is not a supported method and i would try and stay clear of this solution if you can. I would suggest thinking about implementing your code for sharepoint into  ribbon button inside of Microsoft Word.